# Preferrered Salesforce CI / deployment solutions

Tags: metadata, automation, continuous-integration

I am looking at various Salesforce CI / deployment solutions that at least:

- Should be able to deploy based on a custom selection of metadata changes and fixed set of changes (deploy on newest source control check in)
- Be able to compare metadata between orgs
- Be able to merge differences based on the metadata compare

Currently I am finding tools like Flosum, Autorabit and Copado very interesting.

Question: What are your experiences with the above mentioned tools and which one do you think is the 'winner'. Or do you have any other tool suggestion that could cover our needs?

Answer (score 1):

Jakob,

My company, DreamFactory, publishes a metadata management product, SnapShot, that you should look at as well. We just released another product called Cascade that does CI for you (part of the DreamFactory Utilities suite in AppExchange). You can find us at www.dreamfactory.com/force.com

All that said, do not discount the free tools (Force.com IDE, ANT, Jenkins) out there to help with your deployment/ CI needs. For all you know, that just might fulfill all your needs.

Good luck with your search.

Sridhar

Comment: Thank you! Still looking for some actual user experiences for these products though...